# OSError: [Errno 112] Address already in use

Tags: python, server, localhost

I am trying to run server3.py, but whenever I try to do this, I am not able to because I keep getting an error that the server is already in use. So naturally, I tried to find if any other process is using that port and then killing it. However, either I am doing that wrong, or there is some hidden process because no other process is using python.

I am new to servers and local hosts, so any help would be appreciated.
[image: Error on MobaXTerm]

Comment: We don't even know the contents of `server3.py`. Also please post text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Try using netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8000 (mac)

or

netstat -tulpn | grep 8000 (linux)

or

netstat -abno | findstr :8000 (windows)

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you are using flask kind of framework, In any server instance only one port will be listening, in your case port is already been used by other service

```
Change the port number and try
```

If really want to check which port is listening use "netstat commond"

In Linux:

```
 netstat -tulnp
```

In windows:

```
netstat -abno
```

In Mac:

```
netstat -pant | grep LISTEN
```

if output is too lengthy you can grep with port number